# Attach additional information to SKB buffer in Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

Is there any extra or available field in skb struct in the Linux Kernel where I can store my private information during the processing of the packet? If there is such a field, how can I allocate memory to store my data? Basically I want to store the current time stamp in microsecond resolution.

**Note:** I am using Linux Kernel 4.4.83

Answer (score 0):

How about the field [skb_mstamp](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4.83/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L555)? I find this for 4.4.83 kernel, and it seems like microsecond resolution is available.

Also, you may consider [cb](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4.83/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L569) field. The comment above the field in the
struct definition says:

```
/*
 * This is the control buffer. It is free to use for every
 * layer. Please put your private variables there. If you
 * want to keep them across layers you have to do a skb_clone()
 * first. This is owned by whoever has the skb queued ATM.
 */
char            cb[48] __aligned(8);
```

So, this is a 48-byte storage (no memory allocation needed), and in theory you may try use it to store a timestamp. I suggest searching for "skb->cb" usage within *drivers/net/ethernet* sub-tree of the kernel source code.
I hope you will see how the drivers use the field to store whatever information they need there and this comes in handy to you.

Comment: I think I cannot used because it is part on a union which is being used by tcp stack

Comment: OK, I get it. Please find one more option in the updated answer.